# QRegExp Pattern For URLs

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp

I am trying to match google urls from some text that is stored in a variable, using the pattern below.

The urls use double quotes

```
QRegExp regExp;
regExp.setPattern("http://www.google.com/(.*)");
```

I manage to match the url but it unwontedly matches all of the text that is contained after it. I have tried using similar variants like the ones below, but they don't seem to work.

```
regExp.setPattern("http://www.google.com/(.*)\"is"); 
regExp.setPattern("http://www.google.com/^(.*)$\"");
```

Any help to get a regular expression that matches just the url alone.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it is impossible for us to know what is around the urls in your text (quotes ? parenthesis ? white spaces ?), we can create a better regular expression by trying to do a negative match of characters that cannot be part of the url:

```
QRegExp regExp;
regExp.setPattern("http://www.google.com/([^()\"' ]*)");
```

Then you just need to add more possible characters to this negative character class.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you need/want to use a QRegExp?

You could use a QUrl most likely.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into it, because RegExp are quite cryptic to look at

Comment: I prefer this solution, to get the portion of the URL that you're matching with that regex you'd just do something like `QUrl(url_string).path()`